# jQuery .width() and .height() strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why in the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/pHr4z/) .height() returns 95 rather than 100, while .width() returns 200 as expected ? I work with Firefox 3.6.3.

HTML:

```
<table><tr>
   <td id="my"></td>
</tr></table>
<div id="log"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#my {
   border: 5px solid red;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#my").width(200).height(100);
$("#log").append("Width = " + $("#my").width() + "<br />");
$("#log").append("Height = " + $("#my").height());
```

I tried .outerWidth() and .outerHeight() and also .innerWidth() and .innerHeight(), but none of them returns the expected result: [code example](http://jsfiddle.net/pv744/)

But, if I set `position: absolute` it looks [much better](http://jsfiddle.net/kRmLL/) !

Can anyone explain this behavior ?

Comment: On Google Chrome 4.1.249.1064, I get height 95 and width 195.

Comment: This is either a browser issue, or an issue with other CSS being present. In Google Chrome 6.0.401.1 dev, I got expected results. http://jsbin.com/omefu/2

Comment: @Misha: The inconsistencies are being caused by the default padding of the table/td. See updated answer below :).

Comment: I tried to set the padding of `td` to 0px, but it didn't help: http://jsfiddle.net/hBQVA/

Comment: @Misha: If you remove the border it works fine. I don't know why only height() is affected, and not width. It appears to be a browser issue (and not jquery-lib related), as the computed dimensions are 200x95. Looking into this now...

Comment: @Misha: Revised my answer, your best bet would be to find an alternate solution :P.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few jQuery methods for calculating height and width. Try using `outerHeight()`

Excerpt from jQuery Docs: http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

> `.outerHeight( [ includeMargin ] )`
>
> includeMargin - A Boolean indicating
>   whether to include the element's
>   margin in the calculation.

http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/

> `.innerHeight()`
>
> This method returns the height of the
>   element, including top and bottom
>   padding, in pixels.

**Edit:** Setting height() on the td-element is adjusted to include the default padding (1px). The computed dimensions of  are actually...

[image]
<sub>(source: [wordofjohn.com](http://files.wordofjohn.com/with_border.png))</sub>

You should set the default padding to 0px to avoid these issues.

```
table td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Edit 2:** It appears to be a browser issue (probably something related to the rendering engine's method of calculating a table's dimensions). The effects of this behavior will vary across browers. You should find an alternate, table-less, solution using divs.

Comment: outer and inner functions doesn't help here. See updated question.

Comment: I tried to set padding=0 of `td`, but it didn't help. see the updated question.

Comment: This is exactly what I decided to do: to find another solution using `div`s :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't really explain this behaviour better than John, but since this browser inconsistency is still around (at least for those who can't upgrade jQuery version) I thought I would share a workaround for this problem.

Using the HTML DOM properties *clientHeight* and *clientWidth* seems to be consistent over most browsers.

```
$("#my").width(200).height(100);
$("#log").append("Width = " + $("#my").attr("clientWidth") + "<br />");
$("#log").append("Height = " + $("#my").attr("clientHeight"));
```

It's also likely that you may want to use offsetHeight/offsetWidth instead, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this.. I also find it rather strange.. This is my guess.

**The border eats up into the actual height and is neglected by jquery while calculating height**

Comment: The modern box model doesn't do that. Maybe it's an IE6 issue... but shouldn't it be 190 and 90 if that's the case?

Comment: the question is why width and height behaves differently. I would expect both to include or not include the border/padding/margins.

Comment: strange indeed. Using Outline instead of border fixes the issue though. so it has to do with the box model. width:195,height:95 on chrome 14